# Theming embeded entities

Tags: theming, 9

I'm using the **[entity_embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed)** contrib module (8.x-1.2) in drupal 9.4. I embedding entities inside a node body in ckeditor.

The function `mytheme_theme_suggestions_block_alter()` is not called for block entities.

For embedded nodes it's working fine, I have a `node.html.twig` template inside the entity-embed-container. The problem is only for blocks, where are only field templates, no `block.html.twig`.

[image]

Comment: I believe you can configure which view mode(s) should be used when rendering the embedded entities. Then you can manage those displays the same as any other. The option should be in the Configuration > Content authoring area of the admin menu, but I forget if entity embed has its own configuration screen or if it's part of the text formats.

Comment: Just use the view modes.

Comment: I want to control the *markup* in a twig file. I can change the order of fields or properties in the admin "Manage display" page. But I want a custom markup.

Comment: Using view modes can get custom markup....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand well the difference between **block** and **block_content**. Block content don't has its own template what I missed.

Here is an issue about this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2366687

My solution was to use the [block_content_template](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_content_template) contrib module.
So a got my twig file suggestions:

[image]